# jQuery logical operator not working as expected in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have below code which is not working.

```
var day = $("#day").val();
var week = $("#week").val();
var month = $("#month").val();

if (day > week) {
    alert(day > week);
    $('#error').text("Day Limit Must be smaller than Week Limit");
    $('.alert-danger').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert-danger").hide();
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}
if (day > month) {
    $('#error').text("Day Limit Must be smaller than Month Limit");
    $('.alert-danger').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert-danger").hide();
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}
if (month < week) {
    $('#error').text("Week Limit Must be smaller than Month Limit and greater than Day Limit");
    $('.alert-danger').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alert-danger").hide();
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}
```

Here i am getting `day=4` and `week=6` and `month=9`. In this case all `if` conditions are working fine. But `month=10`, second `if` condition not working `(4>10)` is actually `false` but it getting `true`.

What's wrong in my logic?

Comment: `.val()` returns string, you need to convert it to Number

Comment: You're comparing **strings**. There's a duplicate around here somewhere... (`val` returns a string in the normal case [abnormal cases: an empty jQuery object or a non-field element in the jQuery object, in which case you get `undefined`].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the values into integers before comparing

```
var day = parseInt($("#day").val());
var week = parseInt($("#week").val());
var month = parseInt($("#month").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast those values to integers via `parseint` first to compare them as numbers.

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to this question.